# Possible to use AutoMapper to map one object to list of objects?

Tags: c#, automapper

These are my classes:

```
public class EventLog {
        public string SystemId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event {
        public string EventId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class EventDTO {
        public string SystemId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string EventId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I need to go from a single object, with a nested list, to a list of objects with values from the nested list and the parent object. Can this be done in AutoMapper? I realize that I can easily map the Events list and get a list of EventDTO objects and then manually set the SystemId and UserId, it would just be very convenient to let AutoMapper handle it for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You will need these three mapings with one custom converter:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventDTO>(); // maps message and event id
Mapper.CreateMap<EventLog, EventDTO>(); // maps system id and user id
Mapper.CreateMap<EventLog, IEnumerable<EventDTO>>()
      .ConvertUsing<EventLogConverter>(); // creates collection of dto
```

Thus you configured mappings from `Event` to `EventDTO` and from `EventLog` to `EventDTO` you can use both of them in custom converter:

```
class EventLogConverter : ITypeConverter<EventLog, IEnumerable<EventDTO>>
{
    public IEnumerable<EventDTO> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        EventLog log = (EventLog)context.SourceValue;
        foreach (var dto in log.Events.Select(e => Mapper.Map<EventDTO>(e)))
        {
            Mapper.Map(log, dto); // map system id and user id
            yield return dto;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code with [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/):

```
var log = new EventLog {
    SystemId = "Skynet",
    UserId = "Lazy",
    Events = Builder<Event>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build().ToList()
};

var events = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EventDTO>>(log);
```

Comment: How to do the foreach without using global Mapper.Map call? I have different engine instances.

Comment: @Beachwalker, add a constructor to your type converter implementation that takes your engine instance as a parameter. If you're using a DI container such as AutoFac and you've registered your various mapping engines, then just register your new converter as well and the container will resolve the new engine parameter for you. Even if you're not using DI, however, a constructor parameter is the way to go. You'll just have to pass the parameter whenever you construct an instance of the new type converter.

Comment: While this works, mapping from IEnumerable<EventLog> to IEnumerable<EventDTO> doesn't, is there a way around that?

Comment: It's been six year since it was posted, now i want to do something similar is there any better way to do it?

Comment: How to do exactly reverse of this ? I want to go from List<EventDTO> to single object EventLog ?