# Possible to use Automapper to split a source object into multiple destination objects of the same type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm not sure if the following is possible in Automapper given my limited experience with Automapper.

Let's say I have a source and destination object. The mapping between these object was so cumbersome that I created a specific class with a `ITypeConverter<Source, Target>` interface to perform the actual mapping.

Added this in my mappingprofile with the following code:

```cs
   CreateMap<Source, Target>().ConvertUsing(instanceOfMapperClass);
```

Works without problems. However, it is now becoming clear that a single instance of Source should actually map to a collection of Targets. Depending on some business rules 1 Source object should map to 1 or 2 Target objects. I'm not in the circumstance that I can actually modify the Source object.

I tried to accomodate this by changing the interface to `ITypeConverter<Source, List<Target>>` but this doesn't work. It is clear to me that Automapper does not really support mapping to collections but only between concrete types.

Is what I am asking simply not possible or am I missing something here?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects