# map array of list using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an array of objects containing source classes, which has to be mapped destination classes.

```
class A
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Decription{ get; set;}
 }

class B
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<C> { get; set; }
}

class C{
  public string Url { get; set; }
  public string Details { get; set; }
  public string Image { get; set; }
  public string Decription{ get; set;}
}
```

I need to map from List of class B to List class A using auto mapper
Kindly help

Comment: If there are three B objects, each of which contains a List of four C objects, how many A objects are you expecting to receive as a result of the mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to use AutoMapper to map one object to list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects)

Comment: I didn't liked the explanation in the duplicate question, so I tried to explain it a little bit better. I hope I achieved this and it helps you to understand the way you have to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You have to map the information in two steps.

First let's simplify your example:

```
class A {
    public string AttrB { get; set; }
    public string AttrC { get; set; }
}
class B {
    public string AttrB { get; set; }
}

class C {
    public string AttrC { get; set;}
}
```

To create one object of A from B and C you have to create two maps and use them after each other:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<B, A>();
Mapper.CreateMap<C, A>();

var c = new C { AttrC = "AttrCValue" };
var b = new B { AttrB = "AttrBValue" };
var a = Mapper.Map<A>(b); // a with the attribute values of b
Mapper.Map(c, a); // map the attribute values of c also into a
```

I think nothing new for you. But now comes the tricky part. It works with the same principle:

```
class A {
    public string AttrB { get; set; }
    public string AttrC { get; set; }
}
class B {
    public string AttrB { get; set; }
    public List<C> AttrBList { get; set; }
}

class C {
    public string AttrC { get; set;}
}
```

We need another map and a custom converter:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<B, A>();
Mapper.CreateMap<C, A>();
Mapper.CreateMap<B, IEnumerable<A>>().ConvertUsing<BConverter>();

class BConverter : ITypeConverter<B, IEnumerable<A>> {
    public IEnumerable<A> Convert(ResulutionContext ctx) {
        B b = (B)ctx.SourceValue;
        foreach(var aFromC in b.AttrBList.Select(c => Mapper.Map<A>(c))) { // map c attributes into an a object and return it (through Select it's a mapping for all items of the list AttrBList)
            Mapper.Map(b, aFromC); // push the attribute values from b to the aFromC object. Because this is inside the loop, it happens for every Item in the AttrBList array
            yield return aFromC;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
var allAObjects = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<A>>(listOfBObjects);
```