# Automapper: Map single object with list of objects inside to just list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following dto object:

```
public class PriceDto
{
   public string Ticker {get; set;}
   public double Open {get; set;}
   public double Close {get; set;}
}
```

The source objects:

```
public class RemoteData
{
   public Security Security { get; set; }
   public IList<Prices> Prices{ get; set; }
}

public class Security
{
   public string Ticker {get; set;}
}

public class Prices
{
    public double Open {get; set;}
    public double Close {get; set;}
}
```

In result, I want to get collection of `PriceDto` objects. I know how to map `Ticker` property. But, I have no idea how to map `Prices` correctly:

```
CreateMap<RemoteData, PriceDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Ticker, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Security.Ticker));
```

Also, Automapper can't find the configuration because I have single `RemoteData`, but I want to get `IList<PriceDto>`:

```
var json = await rangeUrl.GetJsonAsync<RemoteData>();
var dtos = _mapper.Map<IList<PriceDto>>(json);
```

For the workaround, I created map from `Prices` to `PriceDto` instead of `RemoteData` and then just use `foreach` to assign `Ticker`. But, I want to undertand how to do it with automapper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to use AutoMapper to map one object to list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good approach for this case is to use the `.ConvertUsing`.

```
...
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<RemoteData, List<PriceDto>>()
                    .ConvertUsing(source => source.Prices?.Select(p => new PriceDto
                        {
                            Ticker = source.Security?.Ticker,
                            Open = p.Open,
                            Close = p.Close
                        }).ToList()
                    );
            });
...
```

For more information [read about custom type converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters).

Comment: Yeah, probably custom converter is the best for this task. Thank you.