# AutoMapper - Copy data from Dto to Nested Dto

Tags: c#, automapper

Using AutoMapper, How can I copy `AuthorBooks` object into `Author`?

Below are their properties:

```
public class AuthorBooks
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}


public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Titles { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is nested here?

Comment: Books not nested in AuthorBooks
I need to copy data from AuthorBooks to Author (Author) have nested (Book).

Comment: Can you help me bro ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46757179/815600
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096914/815600
Try this.