# Automapper - Nested Lists

Tags: c#, automapper

I am working with AutoMapper, which I am relatively new with, and I stumbled upon a small mapping problem I was hoping the community could assist with.

So I have two data transfer objects:

```
public class UserDto {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<CharacterDto> Characters { get; set; }
}

public class CharaterDto {
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int CharacterLevel { get; set; }
}
```

and two Domain Entities

```
public class Character {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int CharacterLevel { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The end goal is to be able to save the data taken in by the DTOs into the database via the Domain Entities; however, when it comes to typing up the list of Characters for 'UserDto', I do not know how to map this properly with AutoMapper. I can map it manually with little to no problems... but I can't find anything that helps to explain this or any examples that would help me understand it better.

I have tried doing things like:

```
 CreateMap<UserDto, Character>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.CharacterName, m => m.MapFrom(source => source.Characters[0].CharacterName));
```

However, this seems to only map the 1st entry and not the others. I have also considered mapping the individual mappings like so:

```
 CreateMap<CharacterDto, Character>();
 CreateMap<UserDto, Character>()
     .ForMember(?/*this section I cannot figure out*/)
```

But can't figure out how to associate the the collection of characters to the mapped CharacterDto. I doubt that if I run the code without that association, the code is going to automatically understand that `for each character in characters`, map each character using the appropriate mapper... If I must manually do this, I can... but if there is an AutoMapper way, any help constructing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a collection of Character into your User entity?

Comment: No, only a reference entity that links the IDs, so I can perform a DB search to get a list of all characters that belong to a specific user

Comment: So show us the code where you need to do the mapping so we can point you there how to do that, plesae.

Comment: To clarify: The Domain Entities are one-to-one with the DB tables they are mapped with. I am ingesting a json that populates the DTOs, and in turn I am trying to map the DTOs to the Domain Entities to save that data to the DB. The saving and ingesting are not a problem, just how to use AutoMapper to link the data from the DTO to the Domain Entites so I can save.

Comment: So I think AutoMapper [Getting started](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) explains how to do it for simple DTO and entities like yours.

Comment: @CodeNotFound have you actually read that? No, it doesn't, and the documentation is terrible. No examples, no context, just raw code with minimal information. It is written with the impression you already familiar with everything it says. That was the first thing I read through

Comment: OK I admit it. Can you specify which technology are your using ASP.Net MVC, WPF, etc?

Comment: ASP.Net MVC, I have a UI layer, Data Layer and a Business Layer. I can map the Data Layer to the DB and the UI Layer to the Business Layer just fine, but I can't map the Business Layer to the Data Layer because of the problem above. Also, I updated the Post with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Type converters are you friend here for mapping 1 to many like this. 
Let me know if you need me to go further and get you a working example from your models.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096914/7911333

Comment: No need for more detail, I get this rather well. I don't know why this never crossed my mind. Thank you