# AutoMapper: One-to-many -> One-to one

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm starting to use AutoMapper for my project.
For this I want to do the following 'one-to-many' mapping:

```
public class Team
{
    string TeamName { get; set; }   
    List<Person> Member { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Person
{
    string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
public class TeamDetailsViewModel
{     
    string TeamName { get; set; }
    string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

How to proceed with AutoMapper? Is this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects/18096914#18096914

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use two map methods sequentially like this:

```
team = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Team, TeamDetailsViewModel>(Team);

/* Pass the created destination to the second map call: */
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Person, TeamDetailsViewModel>(Person, team);
```

Another approach is to  apply a very simple extension method:

```
public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(
    this TDestination destination, TSource source)
{
    return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
}
```

and the usage is:

```
var teamDetailsVM = Mapper.Map<TeamDetailsViewModel>(Team)
                .Map(Person);
```

Comment: i find solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects/18096914#18096914

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForMember` method

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
            cfg.CreateMap<Team, TeamDetailsViewModel>().ForMember(des => des.TeamName,
            op => op.MapFrom(team => team.Member.FirstOrDefault().PersonName)));
       
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var team = new Team();
        TeamDetailsViewModel dto = mapper.Map<TeamDetailsViewModel>(team);
```

this method allow you to customize your mapping