# Automapp an object to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am using automapper to map the source and destination class like below

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.P1, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.S1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.P2, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.S2))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.P3, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.S3));
        });
    
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        DestinationClass destObject= mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(sourceObj);
```

Here is it possible to map single object to a list? Like  `cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, List<DestinationClass>>()`.

After the mapping I'm expecting the Destination class list to have the value of source class. That means a list with one element. Is it possible to map a single object to list using .net core?

Comment: That doesn't compile. You have a couple of semicolons that are misplaced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to use AutoMapper to map one object to list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects)

Comment: @PalleDue , updated the code in question

Comment: @YongShun can we do this without custom converter

Comment: Hi, without custom converter, you have to add single `SourceClass` object to `List<SourceClass>` array. Then use the array to map to `List<DestinationClass>` array.

Comment: You mean to declare a List<SourceClass> and using List.Add() add the object and then map this using automapper?

Answer (score 1):

I think, this should do the trick:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var src = new Source { S1 = "Hello", S2 = "World", S3 = "!" };

        // Create list from single item
        var destList = mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(src);
        // Output: [{"D1":"Hello","D2":"World","D3":"!"}]
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(destList));

        // Add item to existing list
        mapper.Map(src, destList);
        // Output: [{"D1":"Hello","D2":"World","D3":"!"},{"D1":"Hello","D2":"World","D3":"!"}]
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(destList));
    }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(d => d.D1, conf => conf.MapFrom(s => s.S1))
            .ForMember(d => d.D2, conf => conf.MapFrom(s => s.S2))
            .ForMember(d => d.D3, conf => conf.MapFrom(s => s.S3));

        CreateMap<Source, List<Destination>>()
            .ConvertUsing((src, destList, context) =>
            {
                if (destList == null)
                    destList = new List<Destination>();

                var dest = context.Mapper.Map<Destination>(src);
                destList.Add(dest);

                return destList;
            });
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string D1 { get; set; }
    public string D2 { get; set; }
    public string D3 { get; set; }
}
```