# How can I use AutoMapper to map certain fields to all members of a List while only mapping other fields to individual members?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

To describe an example, if I have the following source and destination classes:

```
class SourceClass
{
  string Name;
  int Field1;
  int Field2;
}

class TargetClass
{
  string Name;
  int Field;
}
```

Then I would like to be able to make the following list of TargetClass objects:

```
[
  { Name, Field1 },
  { Name, Field2 }
]
```

The trick to this problem is figuring out how to manually assign each target object one of the fields in the source object: the fields are not in a list, so I can't use a loop to assign them.
Please let me know if there is anything else I can elaborate on, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to use AutoMapper to map one object to list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096034/possible-to-use-automapper-to-map-one-object-to-list-of-objects)

Comment: As the source class is right now (and its structure is dictated by a 3rd-party API) it does not apply to my situation as the fields I would like to assign individually are not in a list. Theoretically, I could convert this class into yet another class that could have all the individual fields in a list, but I feel like it would be an inelegant solution.